# SQL left outer join on multiple columns

Tags: sql, join, vertica

According to this [SQL join cheat-sheet](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg), a left outer join on one column is the following :

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b 
    ON a.foo = b.foo
  WHERE b.foo IS NULL
```

I'm wondering what it would look like with a join on multiple columns, should it be an `OR` or an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause ?

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b 
    ON  a.foo = b.foo
    AND a.bar = b.bar
    AND a.ter = b.ter
WHERE b.foo IS NULL 
  OR  b.bar IS NULL 
  OR  b.ter IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b 
    ON  a.foo = b.foo
    AND a.bar = b.bar
    AND a.ter = b.ter
WHERE b.foo IS NULL 
  AND b.bar IS NULL 
  AND b.ter IS NULL
```

?

(I don't think it does, but in case it matters, the db engine is Vertica's)

(I'm betting on the `OR` one)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That depends on whether the columns are nullable, but assuming they are not, checking any of them will do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b 
    ON  a.foo = b.foo
    AND a.bar = b.bar
    AND a.ter = b.ter
WHERE b.foo IS NULL -- this could also be bar or ter
```

This is because after a successful join, all three columns will have a non-null value.

If some of these columns were nullable and you'd like to check if any one of them had a value after the join, then your first (`OR`) approach would be OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any combination of criteria for joining:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.foo = b.foo AND a.bar = b.bar AND a.ter = b.ter
```

The `WHERE` clause has nothing to do with the join itself.
The `WHERE b.foo IS NULL` in first query will return all records from `a` that had no matching records in `b` or when `b.foo` was `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want without LEFT JOIN key words but with (+) you can do like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM a, b 
    WHERE a.foo = b.foo (+)
    AND a.bar = b.bar (+)
    AND a.ter = b.ter (+)
    AND b.foo IS NULL
```